# PhysicsJS - Collision between two bodies never ends

Tags: javascript, physicsjs

I've got this simple js:

```js
Physics(function( world ){

        //Defining object
        var renderer = Physics.renderer('canvas', {
            el: 'viewport', // id of the canvas element
            width: 500,
            height: 200
        });
        
        var ball = Physics.body('circle', {
            x: 250,
            y: 0,
            radius:10,
            restitution: .8,
            mass: 3,
            vx: 0
        });
        
        var box = Physics.body('rectangle', 
            {
                x: 250,
                y: 150,
                width: 50,
                height: 20,
                restitution:.5,
                treatment: "static"
            }
        );
                
        // Add them to the world
        world.add( renderer );
        world.add( ball );
        world.add( box );        
        
        //Add physical behaviours
        world.add( Physics.behavior('constant-acceleration') );//add gravity
        world.add( Physics.behavior('body-impulse-response') );//make obdies bounce (react to impulse)
        world.add( Physics.behavior('body-collision-detection') );//detect collision between bodies
        world.add( Physics.behavior('sweep-prune') );
        world.add( Physics.behavior('edge-collision-detection', //dectect collision with edges
                {
                    aabb: Physics.aabb(0, 0, 500, 500),
                    restitution:.3
                }
            )  
        );
        
        //START playing
        world.on('render', function( data ){
            var renderer = data.renderer;
        });

        // subscribe to ticker to advance the simulation
        Physics.util.ticker.on(function( time, dt ){
            world.step( time );
        });

        world.on('step', function(){
            world.render();
            console.log(ball.state.vel._[1]);
        });

        // start the ticker
        Physics.util.ticker.start();        

    });
```

```css
canvas {border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<script src="http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/assets/scripts/vendor/physicsjs-0.6.0/physicsjs-full-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="viewport" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

that creates a world with a static platform and a ball falling on it. Ball falls and bounces, then bouncing slows and slows but it never ends. I've setted `restitution < 1` in the bodies attributes.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: can you turn that into a working jsfiddle/jsbin/SO-runnable-example?

Comment: @Nemus: We are not able to see any output. Please post a jsfiddle to show your output.

Comment: @Nemus: can you update the code so we don't need to scroll that running example to 3/4th down?

Comment: fun fact: you have a typo in your `box` object definition. That's not how "restitution" is spelled.

Comment: @Nemus: Can you check why I can't see anything in http://jsfiddle.net/kkab/xyqquhbm/1/ ?

Comment: @Aravind You missed `Physics(function( world ){` at the very beginning of your code

Comment: @Nemus: If I set restitution to 0.8 for both circle and rectangle, it bounces forever. http://jsfiddle.net/kkab/xyqquhbm/4/
How did you make it work?

Comment: @Aravind your code works well, bouncing stops. I don't understand what's your issue

Comment: @Nemus: See carefully at the point of contact between the ball and the surface in this link jsfiddle.net/kkab/xyqquhbm/4 . it's still bouncing(very small bounces, yes, but certainly bouncing). Can you notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with the current version of physicsJS. You're code is correct. Try taking from the 0.7 branch on github. You will need to check out the repo and run "grunt dist".

https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/PhysicsJS/tree/0.7.0

Note this is NOT a 0.7 release. This code is still in development. I suggest monitoring physicsjs and getting the actual 0.7 release when it's ready. Should be soon.